# "\r" in textbox input in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I've a textbox for input (numeric value) of 12 digits and on the basis of that number I add some data into datagrid. For the first time when I enter any number it works correctly, but after adding data to datagrid when I enter any new number to textbox, it only gets 11 digits. when I check it in debugging mode, I find textbox having 12 digits including "\r" at the start. I don't know from where its come and creates problem.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks

these are related lines of code

```
GroupedManifest grpManifest = new GroupedManifest();
grpManifest.manifestNumber = txtManifestNumber.Text; // get number from textbox
LayoutManifest.DataContext = grpManifest; // set relevant data to layout
manifestList.Add(LayoutManifest.DataContext as GroupedManifest); // add data to list
dataGridGroupedManifest.ItemsSource = null;
dataGridGroupedManifest.ItemsSource = manifestList; // set data to itemsource of datagrid

txtManifestNumber.Text = string.Empty;           // emtpy textbox
txtManifestNumber.Focus();// set focus on textbox
```

Comment: Please share some of your code

Comment: shared code as u asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I got to solve out my problem is..

I catch textInputStart event and there I check that if textbox.text contains "\r" then make it empty and after that I assign it new input. Still I don't get the reason that why there remains "\r" when am assigning it string.empty but my problem is solved in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the code but from a common sense I can say that Silverlight Text Box uses /r as a new line character. So i guess when you are pressing enter that new line remains.

Try `TextBox.Text = string.Empty;` whenever you enter data into the datagrid.
Please post your code if this doesnot work

Comment: I am doing this one too, but again it does not make any difference and at the start of new input I get "\r"